# Google Sheets - Basic Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working code that I want to be able to pull down on all my rows but at the moment it only returns data from the first cell rather than updating as I drag down.

I have tried so many different things but no luck. Please help me. Here is the current Sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tKy_1BugK1vlq4hPAbjkTCmeunlb6LU0C7pv1rPeSqs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As far I can see you have hard coded the cell in the script   it says to me  getRange('B2').getValue()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from URLs at the column "B" using the custom function.
- The screen shot of your sample Spreadsheet is as follows.

  [image]
- Your current script is as follows. (This script is from your sample Spreadsheet.)

  ```
    function AsxPrice() {
      var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').getValue();
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      var content = response.getContentText();
      Logger.log(content);
      var json = JSON.parse(content);
      var last_price = json["last_price"];
      return last_price;
    }
  ```

In your script, the cell range is constant like `B2`. So in this answer, I would like to propose to retrieve the URLs as the arguments for the custom function. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And in this custom function, when your sample Spreadsheet is used, please put the formula of `=AsxPrice2(B2:B4)` to a cell. By this, the URLs are retrieved from the cells "B2:B4" and retrieve the values.

```
function AsxPrice2(values) {
  const reqs = values.flat().map(url => ({url: url, muteHttpExceptions: true}));
  return UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs).map(r => [r.getResponseCode() == 200 ? JSON.parse(r.getContentText()).last_price : ""]);
}
```

#### Result:

When above scvript is used for your sample Spreadsheet, it becomes as follows.

[image]

#### Note:

- When a lot of URLs are used, an error might occur. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)

Comment: Thank you!!!! It worked perfectly. I love this community.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You only have to modify your function to have an input parameter which is the url

### Code

```
  function AsxPrice(url) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = response.getContentText();
    Logger.log(content);
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    var last_price = json["last_price"];
    return last_price;
  }
```

### References:

- [Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)